# CORS filtering not working in 'Authorization' header

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, angular5

I am trying to add OAuth 2.0 in spring mvc app. User should be authenticated in order to get a api call. I have set a headers in spring mvc controller as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin-api/get-all-order", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity getAllOrders(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String bearerToken) {
        try {
            List<OrderModel> order = orderService.getAllOrders();
            return new ResponseEntity(order, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

For requesting api I have used angular 5. I make a api call in angular like:

```
return this.http.get<T>(this.getAllOrderUrl, {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))["value"],
                "Content-type": "application/json"
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            return this.auth.handleError(error);
        })
```

[image]

I have already enabled a CORS for 'localhost:4200'. CORS filtering works fine on other request.

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,Key");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
```

If I tried in postman it give me a desired result
[image]

**Response Header **
[image]
What am I doing wrong? Please help me out. Hoping for positive response thanks!

Comment: How are you wiring in your `CorsFilter`

Comment: @shinjw - Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: You need to set up your CorsFilter in your WebSecurity or ResourceServer configurers. You'll want to post these configurations

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

to

```
chain.doFilter(req, res);
```

Response may be wrapped and inserted more attribute in header to make sure CORS works.
If you made a test if else here, it might not work.
You can try it and post more information about your CORS configuration in xml or annotation if it's not working.
Hope that help.